# Check whether log4net XmlConfigurator succeeded

Tags: .net, log4net

How to check whether a call to log4net's `XmlConfigurator.Configure` succeeded? I want to make a web service call if the logging configuration could not be loaded properly (i.e. file not existent, file not well-formed, etc.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html):

> To prevent silent failure of log4net as reported as [LOG4NET-342](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-342),
>   log4net supports a way to evaluate if it was configured and also to
>   evaluate messages generated on startup since 1.2.11. To check if
>   log4net was started and configured properly one can check the property
>   `log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository.Configured` and enumerate the
>   configuration messages as follows:
>
> ```cs
> if(!log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
> {
>   // log4net not configured
>   foreach(log4net.Util.LogLog message in log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages.Cast<log4net.Util.LogLog>())
>   {
>       // evaluate configuration message
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, but this works only if the LogManager is initialized once at application startup. I have a dynamic scenario where the configuration can be re-loaded by the user.

Comment: Found the solution myself: your answer in combination with `LogManager.GetRepository().ResetConfiguration()` does the job!

Comment: @D.R.: Great! Feel free to edit the details of how to use that into the answer (I'm not entirely clear on your scenario, so you may want to edit the question as well). Are you using `ConfigureAndWatch` or do you mean something else with "the configuration can be re-loaded by the user"?